# 3 websockets not working (shiba, shushi, luna2)

Tags: binance

I would like to retrieve the current price for these 3 cryptos below:

```
1000Shiba
Shushi 
Luna2
```

I retrieve data for btc or eth but not these cryptos below:

Maybe I made a mistake?

```
new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/1000shibusdt@trade');
new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/shushiusdt@trade');
new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/luna2usdt@trade');
```

I use the binance platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [exchangeInfo](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo) endpoint, these coins/tokens are currently not listed on Binance.

You'll need to retrieve them from other sources.